Corded lawnmower slowly stopped working
I pulled my corded electric lawnmower out for the first mow of the season, and noticed that was kind of weak. Over the next 5-10 minutes it got weaker and weaker, and then finally it just stopped working. What is likely to be wrong with it?

Brand and model? There's not much to these. It could be a bad switch connection, failed motor brushes, or maybe even bad diodes.

Come to think of it, the bearings could have gone. Does the UNPLUGGED mower blade spin freely? It should. If it does not, the bearings may be shot. This may or may not be easily repairable.

If it's Black and Decker, mine had the rectifier progressively burn out. Replacing it was fairly cheap, and not hard for someone who knows what heat-sink grease is..

Did you check for things like dried grass causing the blade to stick?

If the motor brushes are still good, my next step would be to check the switch. I've seen progressive plastic failure in those, or a micro switch failing.
If that isn't it, I've seen these symptoms when a corded mower used a DC motor powered through a bridge rectifier, and the diodes in the rectifier were burning out. When you buy the replacement rectifier, make sure you also get, and apply, heat-sink grease or it will overheat and burn out again.
And of course check all the connections.
If all of that (including the brushes) fails, it's probably time to replace the mower since the motor is suspect.
There isn't much to an old style mower, and it shouldn't be hard to go through these steps if you're reasonably mechanically handy and know how to use a multimeter.

The motor's carbon brush holders may have rusted or corroded over the winter. Motor brushes normally press against the commutator under spring pressure. If the brush holders have a buildup of rust or corrosion, the brushes will stick in the holder instead of sliding freely.
If the brushes are stuck in the brush holder, spring pressure can no longer make up for brush wear. As soon as a small amount of brush wear occurs on a stuck brush and the brush fails to make good contact with the commutator, power will be reduced. Excessive sparking will then wear the brushes to the point that they no longer make contact with the commutator and the motor will lose all power.
The fix involves unplugging the mower, exposing and removing the brushes and cleaning the brush holders sufficiently to allow the brushes to slide freely in the holder. Do not use any lubricant; carbon brushes are self-lubricating.
The situation may involve either one or both brushes.
If one or both brushes are worn down to a small nub, they should be replaced soon.
